# How to identify whether spring batch job is launched from controller or scheduler?

Tags: java, controller, spring-batch, scheduler

I have a spring batch job which is run on scheduler. Also I have created a controller which can be involved to trigger the job.
But the issue is, I am not able to identify whether the job is triggered from controller or scheduler. In job configuration I need to give different sql query as per to the job is invoked from controller or scheduler.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: If the query is different, is it really the same job? Aren't those actually 2 jobs using a common set of logic?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. For the scheduled method it is clear, it runs automatically on a defined schedule. But for the controller, there should be something requesting it to run the job right? Aren't you able to detect that? what about adding some logs in both methods that launch the job?

Comment: You can always add a job parameters and use it to control which SQL gets used, although it's probably better to have separate jobs

Comment: @Thomas Actually you can say those are two different jobs but my requirement is that within one job I have to add logic of scheduler as well as controller

Comment: @johnnyutts I got your point. Will try with two different jobs and put updates here.